# Android performance: drawing to bitmap with canvas in separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to draw to Bitmap with Canvas in the separate thread.

I own the very old tablet (5 years old, 512 MB RAM, Android 2.3.3) and the newer and faster phone (2 GB RAM, Android 4.2.2).

Issue: old tablet is drawing Bitmaps 2-3 times faster than new phone. Bitmaps has the same parameters and the same content.

Why it may be so? May be, devices or Android versions has some hidden parameters that affect Bitmap drawing performance?

Comment: higher resolution causes more calculation time

Comment: I've tried to draw Bitmaps with the same resolution, but it does not matter - old tablet is about 2 times faster.

Comment: Try to use `SurfaceView` which can allow you render bitmap outside UI thread.